# How to Backup and Restore Snap Version of MAAS

Tags: maas

The documentation at https://maas.io/docs/backup doesn't describe how to backup and restore if you are using snaps and packages are now marked as deprecated. How do you back and restore a snap install of MAAS?

Answer (score 0):

Snap runs migration to upgrade the database. Use pg_dump to backup SQL your database as mentioned here:

https://maas.io/docs/snap/2.9/ui/backup

Then install a PostgreSQL instance and create database users

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER \"$MAAS_DB_OWNER\" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$MAAS_PASSWD'"

sudo -u postgres createdb -O "$MAAS_DB_OWNER" "$MAAS_DB_NAME"
```

Then import your database using the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -f dump.sql postgres
```

Finally find and install the oldest available MaaS for your OS.

```
snap info maas
sudo snap install maas --channel=2.7/stable
```

Then init your MaaS using the following command.

```
sudo maas init --mode region+rack --database-host $HOSTNAME --database-user $MAAS_DB_OWNER --database-pass $MAAS_PASSWD --database-name $MAAS_DB_NAME
```

You may check the following document for CLI-Only Operations page

https://ubuntu.com/blog/cli-only-maas-operation